# htacces rewrite - extend url without modifying query

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change:

```
    /?q=bla
```

to

```
    /search?q=bla
```

I have placed rule like:

```
    RewriteRule ^search?q=(.*)$ /?q=$1 [L]
```

but it doesn't work, I would really appreciate some help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match the query string using the pattern inside a `RewriteRule`. You need to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` var inside a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=
RewriteRule ^search$ / [L,QSA]
```

Technically, you don't need the `QSA` flag, since query strings get appended automatically.